# How to get the part of the name in whole column?

Tags: r

I have a column like this:

```
X.at1g01050.1.symbols.atppa1.ppa1.pyrophosphorylase1.chr1.31382.32670reverselength.212
X.at1g01080.1.symbols..rna.binding.rrm.rbd.rnpmotifs.familyprotein.chr1.45503.46789reverselength.293
X.at1g01090.1.symbols.pdh.e1alpha.pyruvatedehydrogenasee1alpha.chr1.47705.49166reverselength.428
X.at1g01220.1.symbols.fkgp.atfkgp.l.fucokinase.gdp.l.fucosepyrophosphorylase.chr1.91750.95552forwardlength.1055
X.at1g01320.2.symbols..tetratricopeptiderepeat.tpr..likesuperfamilyprotein.chr1.121582.130099reverselength.1787
X.at1g01420.1.symbols.ugt72b3.udp.glucosyltransferase72b3.chr1.154566.156011reverselength.481
X.at1g01470.1.symbols.lea14.lsr3.lateembryogenesisabundantprotein.chr1.172295.172826reverselength.151
X.at1g01800.1.symbols..nad.p..bindingrossmann.foldsuperfamilyprotein.chr1.293396.294888forwardlength.295
X.at1g01910.5.symbols..p.loopcontainingnucleosidetriphosphatehydrolasessuperfamilyprotein.chr1.313595.315644reverselength.249
X.at1g01920.2.symbols..setdomain.containingprotein.chr1.316204.319507forwardlength.547
X.at1g01960.1.symbols.eda10.sec7.likeguaninenucleotideexchangefamilyprotein.chr1.330830.337582reverselength.1750
```

The interesting part of this data is bolded below:

```
X.**at1g01050.1**.symbols.atppa1.ppa1.pyrophosphorylase1.chr1.31382.32670reverselength.212
```

I can easlsy get it by applying the function `=MID(B1;3;11)` in Excel. I would like to do the same in R.

The column with the names:

```
tbl_end[,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr`:

```
substr(tbl_end[,1],3,11)
```